# Regd : Getting image from Json url in Android application

Tags: android

I want to get image from Json url.

All the other values I have picked.But there is an issue in picking image.can u guide

Thanks

Comment: You need to parse the json. what is the problem that you are facing and show us some code

Comment: Show your java code. After you get the jpg link, you can use it as variable and assign it to the imageView

Comment: What issue for picking image ?

Comment: what do you mean by imgtag.setTag(strTitle);? as strTitle contains url. set directly with imageview using some library like picasso or universal image loader

Comment: If you already get the image url, you can show it using library like glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide or other

Answer (score 0):

Try with Glide

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);

Glide.with(this).load("http://url").into(imageView);
```

or use Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get strings in 'picture' JSON you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to simply get your bitmap or to set into a view

If you need more help , don't hesitate !

Comment: If that is indeed 'the' issue you should have mentioned that in your post right away. And you should edit your post for it.